# Groovy Script Context and Method Resolution

Tags: groovy

I have an issue with the following Groovy script/

```
nestedView("JS Pipelines") {
  views {
    build_pipelines.each {
      def build_pipeline = it
      buildPipelineView(build_pipeline.build_name + " JS Pipeline") {
        selectedJob(build_pipeline.start_job)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It requires many calls to the `buildPipelineView` method, which sits on the `views` object ([code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/views/NestedViewsContext.groovy#L83)), based on the contents of `build_pipelines`.

When the call to `buildPipelineView` is wrapped in each `{}` call, the method resolves to another `buildPipelineView` method that is defined in a much higher context.  When each block is removed, the method call resolves properly. How can the `buildPipelineView` resolve properly within each call?

Comment: Is it calling `buildPipelineView` on the wrong objet? If so, you could make the receiver explicit `this.buildPipelineView(...)`. In a closure, Groovy method lookup considers the delegate object, too. You can also set properties on the closure to change that lookup resolution policy.

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt store the outer reference, which will be visible to the closure and call this method explicit on that object:

```
nestedView("JS Pipelines") {
  views {
    final outer = it
    build_pipelines.each { build_pipeline ->
      outer.buildPipelineView(build_pipeline.build_name + " JS Pipeline") {
        selectedJob(build_pipeline.start_job)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the [ContextHelper.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/b3bd3488f6c7389be8df0c7e473d0144c364a6ad/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/ContextHelper.groovy#L15) of [job-dsl-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) has changed the delegation strategy of the `views` closure, exactly the brackets of `views`.

In your case, only the `build_pipelines` was wrapped in `views` closure, so you did change the delegation strategy of `each` closure, but `buildPipelineView` closure still kept default strategy.

You can use `getDelegate` to give back the delegation strategy to `buildPipelineView` closure.

```
nestedView("JS Pipelines") {
  views {
    build_pipelines.each {
      def build_pipeline = it
      def d = getDelegate()
      d.buildPipelineView(build_pipeline.build_name + " JS Pipeline") {
        selectedJob(build_pipeline.start_job)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In nested closures, each one has an `owner` which is its immediately containing closure. (See [Delegation strategy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy) in the Groovy docs.) For the closure you pass to `each`, its `owner` is the closure passed to `views`.

A Groovy closure's default [delegation strategy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy_2) is `Closure.OWNER_FIRST`, which means when you access a property or calls a method without explicitly mentioning the receiver [like `buildPipelineView(...)`], Groovy will try to access the property/method on the `owner`, and if there is none, it'll access the property/method on the delegate.

The straightforward solution is to explicitly provide the receiver, e.g. `this.buildPipelineView(...)`.